# how to await for PostAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm making post request, but my debugger doesn't stop after this line:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(_url, data);
```

My full program

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var _url = "https://test.test.test:9100/path/path";
            CheckHttpPostAsync(new { id = 123123, username = "testas" });


            async Task CheckHttpPostAsync(object payload)
            {

                    using var client = new HttpClient();
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    try
                    {
                        var result = await client.PostAsync(_url, data);
                        Console.WriteLine(result);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

and nothing gets written in console, even though im using await

The post request works fine in postman with the same JSON.

edit: added full code

Comment: How do you call this function CheckHttpPostAsync? Can you show the code?

Comment: try `var resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: is your code compilable? using  seems syntax error.

Comment: Using is fine in latest versions of C# where block is no longer needed.

Comment: Is it possible there is an error that is being swallowed on the thread executing the post?  I have seen this a few times where an error is happening in the controller processing the post but it never returns

Comment: added full code. Code does compile and build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should `await` your call to `CheckHttpPostAsync` and make Main as `async Task Main`

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _url = "https://test.test.test:9100/path/path";
        await CheckHttpPostAsync(new { id = 123123, username = "testas" });

        async Task CheckHttpPostAsync(object payload)
        {
                using var client = new HttpClient();
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
                var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                try
                {
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(_url, data);
                    string result =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In more detail: CheckHttpPostAsync is called but not awaited so - the program ends And once it ends, the async is terminated and - well, why would anything be written as the program has ended ;) So, teh answer is correct - the main method must be async and await.

Comment: Why do you call Result on ReadAsStringAsync instead of awaiting it?

Comment: @FrancescCastells yes my bad, updated